# How to debug the Nginx server

Tags: nginx, flask

I play around with `fabric` for deployment of applications on the cloud.

My application is based on `flask` and among the other things it uses `nginx`. I have been successful to make the following example work: https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/

However, after a few modifications, I am now not able to re-start the server and hence see my web app on the browser. I suspect that the problem has to do with the configurations of the Nginx but I can't spot it.

Can you please help be debug the issue? From where should I start?

```
$ fab dep
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] Executing task 'dep'
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] sudo: supervisorctl restart web
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: sudo password:
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: web: ERROR (not running)
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: web: ERROR (abnormal termination)
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: 

[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] sudo: supervisorctl stop web
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: sudo password:
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: FAILED: attempted to kill web with sig SIGTERM but it wasn't running
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: 

[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] sudo: supervisorctl start web
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: sudo password:
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: web: ERROR (already started)
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: 

[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] sudo: supervisorctl restart web
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: sudo password:
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: FAILED: attempted to kill web with sig SIGTERM but it wasn't running
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: web: ERROR (already started)
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: 

[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] sudo: supervisorctl status
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: sudo password:
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: web                              BACKOFF    Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] out: 


Done.
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Usually: /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: After some changes the error has now been disappeared but, when I visit the web site, it says "504 Gateway Time-out". The log you pointed out says : 2015/09/15 16:45:20 [error] 20575#0: *6 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico", host: "YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY", referrer: "http://YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY/index"

Comment: what is more, here as some info about the nginx's health: $ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
$ sudo service nginx reload
 * Reloading nginx configuration nginx